# Expresso Store Stripe integration - "The Token field is required." problem

Tags: expresso-store

I've got a payment form set up with all the requisite stripe javascript in place. I can see that at the point of submission, the stripeResponseHandler is getting fired and is coming back with a token, which is being inserted into my form before it's finally submitted.

```
<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" value="tok_...">
```

So I can't understand why I'm getting this error on my payment form:

> The Token field is required.

I mean, it's there, plain as day. I'm getting returned to the checkout page, with that error, instead of going to the final 'order' page. No order is being created in the CP, so something's definitely not working, but it all looks good according to the Stripe docs.

Is this a known issue? Have I made a silly error somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, just a minor mistake, but that's all it takes.

Try changing this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" value="tok_...">
```

To this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="payment[token]" value="tok_...">
```

As documented [here](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/payment_gateways.html#stripe) :)

Comment: Aw man, my bad, I'm sorry - I followed the stripe docs and they used stripeToken, but I guess I'm actually posting back to EE, not Stripe?

Comment: Yip correct. You're posting the card details to Stripe, but then sending the generated token back to Store, hence you need to follow Store's naming convention there. No worries! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted using the check mark on the left too :)